# HJKL for navigation on PowerShell PSReadLine's MenuComplete function

Tags: powershell, psreadline

I currently am half-happy with the `PSReadLine` module's `MenuComplete` function assigned to my `Tab` key, and was looking for a way to navigate around the offered menu with the HJKL keys. I currently have this on top of my profile:

```powershell
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function MenuComplete
```

I tried the following:

```powershell
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+K -Function UpArrow
```

Which I hoped would at least simulate up arrow key with the combination `Ctrl+K`, but to no avail, as `UpArrow` is not recognized as a function.

If I am allowed to dream, I would like to;

1. Initiate `MenuComplete` using `Tab`,
2. Use HJKL for moving my selection around, and
3. Use `Tab` again for confirming a selection and dismissing `MenuComplete`.

Answer (score 0):

From the PSReadLine docs, there are the **NextSuggestion** and the **PreviousSuggetion** functions: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-7.2#nextsuggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7.2#parameters)

Now, on the Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler page, there is a warn saying that the -Chord parameter is case-sensitive.

So, the correct configuration you need are:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+k -Function PreviousSuggestion
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+j -Function NextSuggestion
```